# Using fetch api to Nodejs backend to update mongoose document

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

so I am using React as a frontend and Node as my backend. Both are independent of each other so I am using fetch to send and receive info. I'm wanting to have a node path i can use to update any info on my user model, but I'm having trouble finding the correct syntax.

let say I have a user model

```
User{
    field1: value1,
    field2: value2
}
```

Here is my current, incomplete, Node route

```
exports.update_user = function(req, res) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, /*data to update*/).exec((err, result) =>  {
        if(err) {res.json(err)}
        res.sendStatus(200)
        
    }) 
}
```

My problem is how do I write the fetch api and the node part so that it only updates whatever field I include in the request.

My thought was something like

```
fetch("http://localhost/update_user, {
    method: 'post',
    mode: 'cors',
    body: JSON.stringify({item_to_update: updated_info})
})
.then(/*do the rest of things */)
```

then, in node, use req.body to update the fields? Honestly I may just be overthinking this.

Comment: I usually just post my updates as an object such as {UserID: xxxxx, UpdateData:{Name:xxxx, Surname: xxx } }. Then in the backend , let {UserID, UpdateData} = req.body. finally mongoose. User.findByIdAndUpDate({id:UserID}, {$set:UpdateData})

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I got it figured out.

for the fetch api I can use this

```
fetch("http://localhost/update_user, {
    method: 'post',
    mode: 'cors',
    body: JSON.stringify({...user, payload:{field1: newValue1})
})
.then(/*do the rest of things */)
```

Then in my backend I can update it by using

```
exports.update_user = function(req, res) {
    User.findOneAndUpdate({id: req.body._id}, req.body.payload).exec((err, result) =>  {
        if(err) {res.json(err)}
        res.sendStatus(200)
        
    }) 
}
```

It currently seems to work the way I'm needing it to. Let me know if theres a better/cleaner way to do this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).